# Problemas con debbuger xdebug, resource not found

Tags: ide, xdebug, phpstorm

tengo un problema que se presenta al realizar debuger, utilizo el IDE PhpStorm, se ha configurado para realizar debugger, para ello y por la version que a fuerzas debo utilizar PHP 5.6 así que se instaló el xdebug para esta version; por otro lado en el chrome utilizo el Xdebug Helper.

bueno el detalle es que cuando los utilizo juntos, me indica el explorador de chrome que no existe la ruta de mi proyecto con un 404

> The requested resource /sistema-de-control-patrimonial/presentacion/codificacion/menu_scp_principal.php was not found on this server.

[image: Error 404]

y este mensaje aparece a pesar de que ya estaba cargado el proyecto en el explorador, en cuanto activo el xhelper y el debug en el Phpstorm casi en automatico me hace esto.

Por costumbre y para utilizar el mysql tengo instalado el xammp y lo ejecuto siempre para tener levantado el servidor de mysql.

Alguien tiene idea de por que sucede esto!!.

Se agradece cualquier aportación